# How can we execute a shell script file from my Android Application

Tags: android, shell

Please Tell me it is possible to run a shell script file from My Android application.

and read the data from script file.

If it is possible than how to proceed , Please give me some guideline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet (from Aaron C)

```
void execCommandLine(String command)
    {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = null;
        OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

        try
        {
            proc = runtime.exec("su");
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
            osw.write(command);
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Log.e("execCommandLine()", "Command resulted in an IO Exception: " + command);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (osw != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    osw.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e){}
            }
        }

        try 
        {
            proc.waitFor();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){}

        if (proc.exitValue() != 0)
        {
            Log.e("execCommandLine()", "Command returned error: " + command + "\n  Exit code: " + proc.exitValue());
        }
    }
```

But this requires root access I think.

You could also try to use [GScript](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=486486)

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
     
        try{
         Process pr;
         pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -n 1 -d 1 ");
         System.out.println("PRO EXEC");
         BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
         
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
 ********************************************

Comment: i am using above code and after executing the application I am not getting any output on ADB debug message. If this commond is executed than where we see this output.

Comment: @anshu I'm not sure but there are various issues in your code. For example I can't see that you use an OutputStream to write the result of the script. You're using a InputStream. Then are you sure that you have root rights?

Comment: hi Rof..Thanks..now i am getting these two lines in adb shell E/execCommandLine()(  590): Command returned error: pwd
E/execCommandLine()(  590):   Exit code: 1
HOW to insure that we have root privilage? My objective to run a script file from my Android Application so I am trying first to run shell commond from application. Thanks a lot. Please give me some guidence.Now I am using same function for executing the commond.

Comment: execCommandLine("echo hi"); i am getting error                                                                Command resulted in an IO Exception: echo hi

Comment: String[] str={"/system/bin/sh","/data/shTest.sh"}          System.out.println("EXEC STRING");
proc = runtime.exec(str);

Comment: Hi Friends Now my script is exeecuting from Android Applicaton but only echo ,pwd , cd these commonds are working but mv this commomnd is not working.

Comment: @anshu are you sure that you have root access? and that your script is correct?

Comment: hmm do you really need to ask for root permission to run a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this to run shell scripts in my android app.  Only thing I've yet to figure out how to do is direct the output to where I want it.  You don't need root for this, which is why I'm posting.

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top -n 1");
 //Get the output of top so that it can be read
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```