# how to include a shell script in android app

Tags: android, shell

I wanted to execute shell scripts from an android app. I am able to pass commands like ls pwd date etc by:

> process p= Runtime.getRuntime.exec("command");

but now I want to execute a shell script necessary for my app. The shell script works fine on linux terminal.

Can you help me help me where to store the shell script and how to call it from program?

First of all is it possible?

Comment: I found the permission your got in shell command is limited. A lot of command you can execute in `adb shell` can't do in `Runtime.exec`. Can  anybody explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Executing an arbitrary shell script from an android app sounds like a bad idea -- but you should be able to put the shell script on the SD card and execute it by passing the full path to the file on the SD card.

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

will get you the full path to the SD card. Check to make sure it's mounted first with:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)
```

Comment: this is a good idea..i can visualise it working..

 But is there no way with sdk, like may be including shell script in assets folder or like adding jar file etc that makes it convenient for distributing the app?

Comment: You can do that. You can access content out of your APK like anything else. One way would be to include the entire shell script as a string and just putt it out of the strings xml. Another way to include it as a resource and then just load it. The nice thing about the SD card method is that the user can modify/view the script by mounting it to their computer.

Answer (score 0):

If possible I would strongly recommend using Java and the Android SDK to replicate your script's functionality.

Otherwise I think you need root, then you need to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932603/how-can-we-execute-a-shell-script-file-from-my-android-application):

```
void execCommandLine(String command)
{
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

    try
    {
        proc = runtime.exec("su");
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
        osw.write(command);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Log.e("execCommandLine()", "Command resulted in an IO Exception: " + command);
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (osw != null)
        {
            try
            {
                osw.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e){}
        }
    }

    try 
    {
        proc.waitFor();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){}

    if (proc.exitValue() != 0)
    {
        Log.e("execCommandLine()", "Command returned error: " + command + "\n  Exit code: " + proc.exitValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: does 4it support pipes? when i tried runtime.getRuntime.exec( "date | cut -d /" /" -f 1 ") it didn't work.